# Mongoid extension .ne

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

First time using Mongoid on a Rails project. 
What does the extension **.ne** represent in a scoping method like so:

```
  scope :subscribed, -> {
       where( :unsubscribed.ne => true )
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the selection operation for ["not equal"](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html).